# CoreData attribute returns as nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am working on a app which uses *core data* contains multiple lists (each one is a separate tab on a tabViewController). Now i have some issues listed below.

- There is only one entity with multiple attributes for all the user inputted data.
- Each list tab is segregated by a bool as true/false. If it's true it's on the list, if false it's not.
- However, if I attempt to fetch them on another tab (another VC) by fetchedResultsController and NSPredicate they return as nil, or give an error of **not key coding compliant**.

How do I get the attribute data to return on another list in order to change the data on the first list.

- example: list 1 has item name and qty
- list 2 needs to fetch the CoreData and recognize there is an item of the same name on list one and subtract list 2's qty from list 1's item's qty.

Any ideas on why this isn't working/ know how to fix it? thanks in advance

FetchRequest (on list 2):

```
func itemFetchRequest1() -> NSFetchRequest{

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"pitem =%@", item.pitem!)
        return fetchRequest

    }
```

Doing the math:

```
func subtractPqty(){
if (item.ringredients == item.pitem){
            //get value of string
            let stringNumber0 = item.rqty0
            let stringNumber1 = item.pqty
            //convert string to Int
            let numberFromString0 = Int(stringNumber0!)
            let numberFromString1 = Int(stringNumber1!)
            //get sum of Int
            let sum = (numberFromString1)! - (numberFromString0)!
            let myInt:Int = sum
            //convert back Int back to string
            let myString:String = String(myInt)
            //delclare string as qty.
            item.pqty = myString

        }else{
            print(item.pitem)
            print(item.ringredients)
        }
}
```

If it makes more sense to see the func that creates an item, I have included it as well.

```
func createNewitem() {
    guard self.item == nil else {
        print("trying to create a new item while there is already one.")
        return
    }
    // just creating an empty item and let give the job to filling it to editItem method.
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    // assign the empty item to self.item.
    let item = List(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)


    item.mplist = true
    item.mpcross = false
    // assign the new item to self.item
    self.item = item

    item.mpitem = Recipe.text
    item.mpcategory = mealOfDay.text
    item.ringredients = recipeItem.text
    item.mpdate = dayOfWeek.text
    item.rqty0 = rqty.text
    itemFetchRequest1()
    func subtractPqty()
    }
```

The first list is created the same just with plist, pcross, pitem etc.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's difficult to tell, from the extracts you've provided, exactly what you are trying to achieve and what's going wrong.  Can you add more, including the specific error and the line where it occurs.

Comment: Error is - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb). The lines it's occurring on is on the itemFetchRequest1() when it is called in the createNewitem function, the `pItemFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"pitem == %@", pItem!)` in the itemFetchRequest1 function, and in the line where it calls the createNewitem function when the save button is pressed. It appears that the main line causing the issue is the predicate fetch in the itemFetchRequest1 function. It returns nil when it returns the information. This causes the other errors (I believe).

Comment: As far as additional code, I am not sure what you need and don't want to post irrelevant code for you to sift through. Do I need to post the entire code file? Or, if it is easier for you to see the entire code and data model from github.com.

Comment: In your `createNewItem` method, you create a new List object and assign this to `self.item`.  You set various attributes on that object - but you do not set the `pitem` attribute.  So this attribute will be nil (unless you've specified a different default value in the model editor or in the List class).

Comment: The same createNewItem function that is used on the mplist list is used on the plist list to create an item and displays it on the plist (the attributes change to the attributes displayed on the plist). I am trying to get the app to check the items displayed on the plist and change its quantities when an item is added to the mplist. Basically, the mplist is the meal planning (which users plan meals and add ingredients and qty to be used). I am trying to get it to check the plist for that item and, if it exists, adjust the quantities when the user adds these ingredients to the meal planner.

Comment: How do you match an item on the mplist with an item on the plist?

Comment: That's the itemFetchRequest1 function I call when the item is created on the mplist. I used the predicate to filter the pitem attribute located on the plist. And then if the ringredient attribute on the mplist equals the pitem, the subtractPqty function adjusts the qty on the plist for pitem by the qty added to the ringredient. However, it doesn't appear to be searching for a match on the plist but searches the item created for the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123024/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-will-zimmer).